# Blackarch linux boot error on grub

Tags: linux, boot, grub, arch-linux, bootloader

I came across an error after installing blackarch linux from live iso. Grub bootloader says filesystem unknown. I was able to use these commands and boot to another linux that i had installed:

```
Set boot=(hd0,gpt10)
Set prefix=(hd0,gpt10)/boot/grub
Insmod normal
Normal
```

Grub bootloader opened, showed me parrot linux on executing these commands on grub rescue.

But when I tried the same with (hd0,gpt12) on which black arch is installed, it shows that a boot file was not found right after executing the command `insmod normal`.

Please help me out of this.

Comment: There is also a StackExchange site called AskUbuntu.com you would probably do better to ask there. What about Grub 2? What is the file system you are using with BlackArch? More information will bring you better results with people helping with something others cannot see. Good luck.

Comment: Boot your machine on Parrot Linux, as *root user* try to run the cmd **fdisk -l**, then copy and past its output on your question.